# Receive signal after notification clicked

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I fire a notification from `MainActivity` class. When user click the notification, i'd like to return back to `MainActivity` class and **execute a method**. I'd also like to know **which notification is clicked** (Assuming that i fire multiple notifications with different `id`). Here what i did and it didn't work

Inside `MainActivity.class`:

```
private void showNotification(String title, String message, int id) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setAction("mAction");
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Same inside `MainActivity.class` i create a `BroadcastReceiver` class but **it never got called**:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals("mAction")) {
                //execute my method here
        }
    }        

}
```

I did add `MyBroadcastReceiver.class` receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" > </receiver>
```

Comment: Have you added the action string to the <reciever?

Comment: `<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"> </receiver>` that what i did, what else should i add?

Comment: When user clicks the notification he/she will be taken to the MainActivity.. What makes you think that your `BroadcastReceiver` will be invoked.? 
The activity will be created and you can see that `mAction` in the `onCreate` of your `MainActivity`..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html You need to add <intent filter> and <action> down to the enclosing <reciever>

@Varun getBroadcast() is somewhat same to sendBroadcast(), see the docs. And you are right, he needs to set BroadcastReciever class instead activity class. :)

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski for my problem i don't have any specific action needed to add. Which action you think should i add here?

Comment: Your Intent is referring to MainActivity. And No, getBroadcast is not at all similar to sendBroadcast. `sendBroadcast` is specifically used to sendBroadcast messages.!

Comment: @Varun Are you sure? This is from docs: `Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast, like calling Context.sendBroadcast().`

Comment: I dont see why the broadcast receiver is even coming in the picture. the Intent created by @laph is pointing to an Activity. So why would you expect the BroadcastReceiver to be invoked?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski `getBroadcast` will only return a `PendingIntent`, which can be used to do a sendBroadcast, but when you do a `getBroadcast` a broadcast is not made.

Comment: @Varun thanks, your suggestion solves my problem, please allow me to post the answer

Comment: Glad to have posted something that was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Varun suggestion, here how to solve my problem.

In `showNotification` i replace `.setAction` to `.putExtra` and change `.getBroadcast` to `.getActivity`:

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);           
    resultIntent.putExtra("mAction", id); // put id here you know which notification clicked
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); // change getBroadcast to getActivity
```

No longer need `MyBroadcastReceiver` class instead i add some lines in `onCreate()` to get intent result:

```
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("mAction")){
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        int id = extra.getInt("mAction");
        if(id == 1) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```